# How could I solve a problem I have with my sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web system that only when it becomes mobile has the function of moving 2 buttons down, I did it with css putting a padding-top: 10% in my body; creating a space so that my buttons cannot cover the description of my first table, the problem I have is that this affects my siderbar leaving a space of 10%, how could I make that hole not affect my siderbar. I attach my html code:
and image like this: https://ibb.co/7VXK3p3
I am using AdminLTE 3 template and bootstrap

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .container-fluid2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    /*  background: red */
    }

    .row2{
    z-index:70;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    /*  padding-top:70px; */
    /*  background-color: violet */
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
.body2{
    padding-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
/////////MAIN INDEX THEN I HAVE MY OTHER VIEW WHERE IS MY BUTTONS/////////

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/style2.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/style2.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-navbar-fixed body2 sidebar2">
  <!-- Navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4" >
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="index.php" class="brand-link elevation-4">
      <img src="../template/dist/img/logowira.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Wirac</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar" >
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="../template/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block"><?php echo $_SESSION['S_USU']?></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SidebarSearch Form -->
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group" data-widget="sidebar-search">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sidebar" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-sidebar">
              <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

///////CODE WHERE IS MY BUTTONS/////////////
  <section class="content-header" >
      <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid container-fluid2">
      <div class="row row2 justify-content-around">
          <div class="col-sm-4" id="aprobado">
            <button type="button" id="btnconfir" class="btnapro btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Aceptar_Venta()">Aprobado</buttton>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" id="rechazado">
            <button type="button"  id="btnrech" class="btrecha btn btn-block btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="Rechazar_Venta()">Rechazado</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are using bootstrap? Use the spacing utilities like `mt-3` or `pt-3` for padding/margin top

Comment: yes, i use bootstrap, how would it be please?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You'll need to provide enough information so we can help. Please tag your Bootstrap version and included it via CDN in your snippet demo.

Comment: I already wrote you everything what to do. Should only take you a couple of minutes to figure out